Intel Wi-Fi 6E AX211 drops connection
My computer has a dual boot of Ubuntu 24.04 and Windows 11. It also has an Intel Wi-Fi 6E AX211 network adapter. The connection is dropped after 5-10 minutes after a successful connection. This happens since 3-4 days (maybe after a recently updated kernel, I don't know. I use 6.8.0-49-generic).
On Windows 11 Pro it works fine and before it worked fine on Ubuntu too.
Sometimes it works OK for more than hours without dropping the connection.
How should I debug it?
lspci result:
Network controller: Intel Corporation Meteor Lake PCH CNVi WiFi (rev 20)

dmesg|grep wifi result:
loaded firmware version 86.fb5c9aeb.0 ma-b0-gf-a0-86.ucode op_mode iwlmvm

dmesg after connection dropped

[ 7702.230895] wlp0s20f3: associated
[ 7702.241434] wlp0s20f3: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as
advertised by 1c:61:b4:4f:a3:f2
[ 7705.303879] audit: type=1107 audit(1733773359.390:849): pid=2200
uid=101 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined
msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system"
path="/org/freedesktop/login1"
interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="PropertiesChanged"
name=":1.15" mask="receive" pid=12106
label="snap.thunderbird.thunderbird" peer_pi d=2232
peer_label="unconfined"
exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=101 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'

The last one is maybe from Thunderbird.

Does iwconfig show power management on?

yes, power management is on.

I turned it off. But I use it constantly, so I don't know what is this help for me.
